# Bringing forward objects while spawning UI-objects in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a flappy bird-game as a start up-project to learn the basics of Unity.

I've created pipes that spawn upon starting the game (an UI-object), and these pipes always spawn in the front of everything else, which means that my score text falls behind the pipes, together with my game over-menu.

I understand that UI-objects that render last will come up closest to the camera, and this is the only item that spawns so I guess that's the reason why it makes no difference how I set the camera.
Are there any scripts or other ways around this? How do I bring my text forward? My text is also an UI-object.

I solved this - I assigned different levels to the cameras that I was told to do :)

Comment: While sorting layers may be a good solution to the actual problem, I believe this is a type of [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/): You want to render pipes. Instead of drawing pipes "the proper" way using a [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html), you are using a UI element and have issues with it. In my opinion, you should go one step back and draw the pipes as sprites instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using Sorting Layers.

> SortingLayer allows you to set the render order of multiple sprites easily. There is always a default SortingLayer named "Default" which all sprites are added to initially. Added more SortingLayers to easily control the order of rendering of groups of sprites. Layers can be ordered before or after the default layer.

**Edit > Project Settings > Tags & Layers**
or click **Tag** or **Layer** at the top of the inspector on any gameobject and selecting **Add...**
or click on the Sorting Layer dropdown/popup and select **Add Sorting Layer...**

[image]

Once you have added your new sorting layers, set the order by dragging the layer up or down in the Sorting Layers list.  The order of the list is back to front, meaning layers appearing at the top of the list are behind those appearing later in the list.

[image]

Now assign the sorting layer to the sprite renderer.  You can additionally set the order in layer, which allows for fine grain control of objects in a single layer.

[image]

**For Normal UI Elements**

To get the normal ui elements (Text, Image, etc) to render behind your sprites is a little different.  Make 2 canvas objects, set the render mode on both to Screen Space - Camera.  Assign your camera to both canvas'.  Use one canvas for the normal UI elements, and the other canvas for your sprites.  Now you can control the order using the Sorting Layer property of the canvas.  This method does change how 3d objects render in relation to the ui elements, because the canvas no longer overlays on top of the other scene objects.